# How can this "Unexpected Indent" error in Python be fixed?

Tags: python

I have a simple piece of code that I'm not understanding where my error is coming from. The parser is barking at me with an *Unexpected Indent* on line 5 (the *if* statement). What is the problem here?

```
def gen_fibs():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        a, b = b, a + b
        if len(str(a)) == 1000:
            return a
```

Comment: Replace all "space-space-space-space-space" with "tab"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just copy+pasted your code, then you used a tab on the line with the `if` statement. Python interprets a tab as eight spaces and not four. Don't ever use tabs with Python<sup>1</sup> :)

<sup>1 Or at least don't ever use tabs and spaces mixed. It's highly advisable to use four spaces for consistency with the rest of the Python universe.</sup>

Comment: Ahh! I copy and pasted this code from other code I had. Good grief. I commented on an answer above, but I didn't realize what had caused it until your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Back at zero now ;) I was about to say the same thing. I would recommend running a search and replace on `\t` characters and replacing them with `[four spaces]`.

Comment: Because you decided to pontificate on a holy war instead of simply answering the question.

Comment: @Nicholas Knight. There's no holy war here. The issue is long over and decided by PEP-8. Hope that clears up your obvious confusion :)

Comment: PEP-8 is a style guide, not a commandment, and not everyone agrees with all of it. Lose the fundamentalism.

Comment: @Nicholas Knight - Given that you're the one downvoting over a 'holy war', I wouldn't be so quick to drop the f-bomb. Most python projects that I have __Ever Looked At__ follow this convention. It is pretty standard. A better example of an oft-ignored part of PEP-8 is `under_score` vs `camelCase`.  Please compose your rebuttal in Emacs.

Comment: If you'd said "don't ever use spaces with python", I would have downvoted, too. I'm reacting to fundamentalism, not the side it's on. Incidentally, most C projects I have **Ever Looked At** use tabs to indent, but I would never think for an instant to tell a C programmer "don't ever use spaces with C".

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing tabs and spaces. Tabs are *always* considered the same as 8 spaces for the purposes of indenting. Run the script with `python -tt` to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you aren't mixing tabs with spaces or something, because your code pasted verbatim doesn't produce any errors.

Comment: Yeah, this was it. I use TextMate on the Mac to write my code, and I use the tab key to indent (it puts in the 4 spaces). In the editor it looked fine, but when I pasted it in here, there was an extra tab on the if statement. I switched it to a manual four spaces and it worked. Bizarre.

Comment: You can set up TextMate to always use spaces in .py files.

Answer (score 1):

The line with `a, b = b, a + b` is indented with 8 spaces, and the `if` line is indented with 4 spaces and a tab.  Configure your editor to never ever insert tabs ever.

(Python considers a tab to be 8 spaces, but it's easier just not to use them)

Answer (score -1):

Check whether your whitespace in front of every line is correctly typed. You may have typed tabs instead of spaces - try deleting all the space and change it so you use only tabs or only spaces.